# First constructor that is called in a csharp program

Tags: c#, constructor

Theory question:
What is the first Constructor called at all? Is it the first constructor used in the written code or are there others called on startup?

A different wording of the same question:
Are any constructors called before the "actual" program runs?

--
A friend of mine was asked "What is the first constructor in your program" and I thought this might actually be a really tough, deep question since it requires alot of knowledge about how csharp actually works. Therefore my question.

Comment: First within your application code? Then it should be the static constructor of the class your `Main` method exists in

Comment: [Static Constructors C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).

Comment: Also [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9) Top-level statements and Module Initializers.

Comment: Before your application code is unknowable: it is implementation-defined. Could be none, most likely lots of initalization code setting up method-tables, JIT, GC, thread-pool etc